javax.servlet.Filter ClassNotFoundException OAuth2
I'm trying to implement OAuth2.0 in my Spring Boot backend service, but I'm encountering the following error when adding my SecurityConfig class:
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    ...

This issue occurs specifically when I add the following configuration class:
package com.trojan.loginserver.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}

Here's my pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.trojan</groupId>
    <artifactId>login-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>login-server</name>
    <description>login-server</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version> <!-- Update to the latest version -->
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>openjdk:17-jdk-slim</image>
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>trojan2877/login-server</image>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I believe the issue might be related to missing servlet dependencies, but I'm not sure how to resolve it in Spring Boot 3.x. I've checked similar issues online, but nothing seems to work.
Has anyone else encountered this issue or have suggestions on how to resolve it?
Link to project: GitHub Link

Can you show the full stack trace?

If you're using Spring Boot 3, then you shouldn't be using a library that requires javax.servlet.Filter, you should use a library that requires jakarta.servlet.Filter.

The stacktrace should give you a suggestion to resolve some of dependencies that are using Java EE libraries. Recently It happened to me to resolve a dependency issue from here.

The currently linked duplicate is completely unhelpful. Please post the stack trace in order for us to find the correct duplicate for you.
